# Utilizing IBOutlets/IBActions from external loaded Nib

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, interface-builder

Forgive me for my noob questions, but I really need some help. I am learning IOS development with swift2. Unfortuantely, the tutorials I've followed/done don't really get into much advanced stuff when it comes to working with Views/Nib files.

Anyhow, I am trying to create a custom class that will load my Nib and I can work with the Outlets/Actions of the newly instantiated class of type UIView.

I was able to find some information that got me to being able to load my view properly and insert it into my tableHeaderView, but I am kind of lost. I need a little guidance.

**ReserveHeaderCell.swift**

```
class ReserveHeaderCell : UIView{


    @IBOutlet weak var ReserveHeaderImageView: UIImageView!


    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "ReserveHeaderCell", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! ReserveHeaderCell
    }

}
```

I set the class in my xib to be this class, further, the outlet refers to a UIImageView within the parent view.

**ReserveViewController.swift** contains:

```
let reserveHeaderFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, 164)
let rhCell = ReserveHeaderCell.instanceFromNib()
rhCell.frame = reserveHeaderFrame
ReserveTableView.tableHeaderView = rhCell
```

And this all works. The frame gets created, the xib is loaded and added to the view. Great, the problem is, I don't have access to my IBOutlets that are defined in the **ReserveHeaderCell.swift** file. Also, I really don't know if this is the correct way to accomplish what I am trying to do.

What I am trying to accomplish (done with obj-C)

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                        loadNibNamed:@"HeaderNib"
                        owner:self
                        options:nil];

        self = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        // ACTIONS GO HERE

    }
    return self;
}
```

That way I have access to any of the IBOutlets that are created (in obj-c the H file, but for my case, it would be the class, right?)

using the obj-c method, I can simply call view.outlet = "" and get access to them.

Any help is appreciated. Any links to tutorials that could help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to init your nib file

```
let view = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MenuHeader", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView)
tableView.tableHeaderView = view
```

Then your MenuHeader will be a normal .xib file with your cell inside it, just remember to adjust the constraints appropriately to fit on all the screens that you want. If you already have a class for your UIView you have to connect your nib file with this class and then you can use "view.label.text" and then change your values. Remember to keep a reference of this view or just create a new one when you have to change the header information. If you want to track an action the best way would be through a delegate method or using the NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: I want to load it using the custom class, though. Not simply just load it directly into the tableview. The reasoning for this is because some of the xib will have a lot of input/outlet. For specific nib it would probably be OK, but this solution will help me when implementing others in a similar fashion that have much more detailed layouts/outputs/actions.

Comment: I apologize, you were pretty much right here. The one exception was that I needed to change it from as! UIView to as! MyCustomClass. Also, I changed it to be UINib() function instead. But this gave me the general direction. Thanks